# MoSync C++ Cross Platform Development

Tags: c++, mosync

[MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/)

1. Can I use C++11 features such as smart pointers while using MoSync IDE?
2. What is the underlying compiler used by MosSync IDE ?
3. Is it worth investing time and money on MoSync ? Is it mature enough ?

Answer (score 4):

After reading about MoSync in various forums as well as looking at some videos on youtube, I decided to take the plunge.

Installed MoSync IDE (a modified eclipse IDE). It is using GCC PIPIL Compiler v2:11:50:55:Aug 26 2009 (O2)

A1. No C++11 is yet to be supported.

The following code failed to compile

```
void keyReleaseEvent(int keyCode, int nativeCode)
{
    auto lambda = [](const int & val)->int{return val*val;};
    int alpha = lambda(10);
}
```

A2. GCC PIPIL Compiler v2:11:50:55:Aug 26 2009 (O2)

A3. Not sure. Will come back in some time and update this answer.